# Swift - Add same navigation bar items to every page

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add the same navigation bar items to every tab in my application. I currently have them set up correctly in my homeController, but I want to move the code to a separate file and remotely implement it wherever I want.

For example: adding a [search] icon to the left side of the navigation bar without having to use the same code in every swift file.

I don't know whether I should create an enum, protocol or class. What is the best way to do this?

```
let menuButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSearch), for: .touchUpInside)
menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_search"), for: UIControlState())
let menuBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [menuBarButtonItem]

func openSearch() {
 // Some code
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have different button actions on every screen or exactly the same everywhere?

Comment: The same button actions on every screen.

Comment: May be you should try to use UINavigationController with built-in navigation bar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My recommended approach to this would be to create a base view controller class and make all your individual view controllers inheirit from this rather than directly from `UIViewController`.

Whilst you could do a quick and dirty extension as Umair suggests, this isn't practical for other applications whereas a base view controller allows you to basically add functionality/customise appearance of any aspect of all view controllers within your app.

Here is some example code:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let menuButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSearch), for:    .touchUpInside)
        menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_search"), for: UIControlState())
        let menuBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [menuBarButtonItem
    }

    func openSearch() {

    }
}
```

Then for all view controllers in your app, just make the declaration:

```
class SomeRandomViewController: BaseViewController { }
```

**EDIT:**

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you will have to do this in every *base* class. (UIViewController, UITableViewController, UITabViewController etc...) There is a way around this but it is often considered one of the dark arts of the Objective-C runtime. I am of course talking about **method swizzling**. The following code essentially swaps the implemetations of `UIViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` and a custom method. It is totally safe if done correctly, and a correct implementation is shown below.

```
extension UIViewController {
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        if self !== UIViewController.self {
            return
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("viewWillAppear:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("extended_viewWillAppear:")

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    func extended_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.extended_viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Call your code here that you want to run for all view controllers, table view controllers, tab view controllers etc...
    }
}
```

Some developers can't stand the above concept, and you should be aware that it could potentially change in a future release of iOS and break. That said, it won't get your app rejected as it is an actual programming technique.

Comment: How should I deal with the fact that some controllers in my application are  UITableViewControllers or even UICollectionViewControllers. This would create a lot of inheritance errors.

Comment: @DennisvanMazijk Yes that is the only downside. `UITableViewController` does not inherit from `UIViewController` so will not automatically gain this functionality. You would need to create a similar thing for `UITableViewController` and indeed `UICollectionViewController` as well. It's not ideal but is widely regarded as the correct/best way of achieving this functionality nonetheless. It is the proper OO approach.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the solution, so I will see how I can adjust my code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

You Can Use it Very Easily by making an extension of UIViewController

extension UIViewController {

```
func setupRemainingNavItems() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "your-icon"))
    titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    titleImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage (named: "Group 6"), for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapbutton), for: .touchUpInside)
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
}

@objc func tapbutton(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    print("tap")
}
```

}

Uses:

call it in ViewDidLoad()

setupRemainingNavItems()

**Updated code for Swift 5**

Firstly declare some variable globally,

```
 let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

 let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top

 let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom

 let guide = window?.safeAreaLayoutGuide

 let height = guide?.layoutFrame.size.height

 let safeAreaWidth = guide?.layoutFrame.size.width

 let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4

 let parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y:( UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 65) - bottomPadding!   , width: safeAreaWidth!, height: 65))

 let blurparentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: safeAreaWidth!, height: 60))

 let backImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 7.5 , y: 20, width: 20, height: 20))

 let cartImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 6.5 , y: 16.5, width: 25, height: 27))

 let cartLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 14, y: -4, width: 14, height: 14))

 let lblWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2

 extension UIViewController {

 func navigationBarDesign() {

       let parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: topPadding!, width: safeAreaWidth!, height: 60))
       parentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: Colors.appColor)
       let back = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 40, height: 60))
       let title = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: lblWidth - lblWidth/2, y: 0, width: lblWidth, height: 60))
       let cart = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50, y: 0, width: 40, height: 60))

       blurparentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: Colors.blackColor)
       backImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Your-Icon")
       cartImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Your-Icon")

       let titlelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lblWidth, height: 60))
       titlelabel.font = UIFont(name: "Segoe UI", size: 20.0)
       titlelabel.text = "Home"
       titlelabel.textAlignment = .center
       titlelabel.textColor = .black



       let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50))
       let cartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50))


       cartLabel.textAlignment = .center
       cartLabel.textColor = .white
       cartLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 8.0)
       cartLabel.setViewRounded()
       cartLabel.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: Colors.yellowColor)
       cartLabel.isHidden = false
       backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickBack), for: .touchUpInside)
      // cartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickCart), for: .touchUpInside)



       back.addSubview(backImage)
       back.addSubview(backButton)

       title.addSubview(titlelabel)

       cart.addSubview(cartImage)
       cart.addSubview(cartButton)
       cartImage.addSubview(cartLabel)

       parentView.addSubview(back)
       parentView.addSubview(title)
       parentView.addSubview(cart)
       parentView.addSubview(blurparentView)

       blurparentView.isHidden = true

       view.addSubview(parentView)
   }

   @objc func clickBack(){

       parentView.isHidden = false
       navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)

   }
}
```

Uses:

call it in ViewDidLoad()

navigationBarDesign()

Answer (score 0):

**For those in future**

If `subclassing` and `hardcoding buttons` is not your way here is my solution:

1. Add desired buttons to `navigation bar` in `Storyboard`
2. Connect `outlets/actions` to your `TabBarController`
3. Assuming your flow is `TabBarController --> NavigationController --> tab1/tab2/tab3` in `viewDidLoad()` of `TabBarController` add:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let viewControllers = viewControllers {
        for nvc in viewControllers.compactMap({$0 as? UINavigationController}) {
            let left = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
            let right = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
            nvc.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Common Title"
            nvc.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = left
            nvc.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = right
        }
    }     
}
```