# Add same NavigationBar on every page in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I recently try to develop an application in swift and wanted to make a navigation bar which is the same on every single view.
I tried different approaches. The best one so far was a solution from another stack overflow-question you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780919/swift-add-same-navigation-bar-items-to-every-page)

The solution from Jacob King works for me, but because I am relatively new in Swift, I am concerned if his approach would add a second, third, fourth,... navigation bar every time I navigate between two views, which both inherit the navigation bar? And if that is true, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for all efforts in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the code, he says you would need to declare each ViewController. In his case, when he taps the open search button the code would execute the open search function, so from the looks of it it would not create infinite amounts of navigation bars. Remember in the future after implementing your code you can always build and run your application to test things like these to make sure I’m right. It never hurts to try! - Colin

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to run the application and I couldn't tell from the animation if the navigation bar's are overlapping or not.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Still, from what you described the navigation bars wouldn't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a viecontroller class with a navigation bar and then all the viecontrollere you will have to put

miaviewcontroller: viewcontroller_with_bar